# Keeping Tablix and Subreport on same page

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a report with a subreport in the report body, followed by a tablix in the report body. I have another report with the tablix above the subreport.

I don't want there to be a page break after the objects in the report, I've tried setting the various options according to various online articles but no joy.

What are all the settings that need to be in place on both the subreport and the tablix to ensure there is no page break?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the page layout options?  I.E. portrait vs. landscape, page size, etc?  If not, you can access them in Report Builder 3.0 On the Home tab, in the Layout group.  Or for Visual Studio with BIDS, On the View menu, point to Toolbars, and click Layout.

If that doesn't work, does it seem to be page breaking solely on length of items on the page, or is it breaking on groups?